Adding record offset and position in the message headers while writing to Kafka topic
I am new to Kafka and Kafka Connect, I am using File Pulse source connector and reading the data from a file and writing it to the Kafka topic.
The headers contains the metadata like this in the topic when the records is written.
{
  "lastModified": "1715804828146",
  "hash.digest": "25",
  "name": "test",
  "uri": "file:/filepath",
  "contentLength": "24",
  "system.hostname": "",
  "hash.algorithm": "",
  "system.inode": "10",
  "hostname": ""
}

But I want to add record offset as part of message headers above. Example:
"offset.timestamp": ""

How can I achieve this to add offset related info in the headers like offset.position, offset.rows, etc?
I tried to add $offset.timestamp in the headers by adding properties in connector file but it did not work. Reference doc - https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/accessing-data-and-metadata/#source-metadata
Can someone help how can I add more fields to the message headers while using Kafka Connect file pulse source connector? This is record offsets. Basically records within a file.
